# PyCharm vagrant Connection failed

Tags: ssh, pycharm, vagrant, sftp

Собственно вся проблема заключается в том, что не могу понять почему не соединяется.

Настройка соединений с другими серверами ( VPS ) проходит прекрасно. Здесь же

[image: Connection failed]

Настройки стандартные

[image: Настройки vagrant]

putty, winscp соединяются без проблем

Немного другое сообщение при настройке Deployment сервера

[image: Algorithm negotiation fail]

Прошу помочь с решением проблемы, так как не знаю куда смотреть, что искать.

Answer (score 2):

Мне помогло такое решение:

- Запускаем образ `vagrant up`.
- Подключаемся по `vagrant ssh`.
- Редактируем конфиг SSH (*/etc/ssh/sshd_config*), вставив в него следующую строку:

  > KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
- Перезапускаем SSH демона (`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`) на Debian.
- В PyCharm спокойно подключаемся.

Я, конечно, перезапустил Vagrant и PyCharm, но это чтобы душу успокоить.

[Оригинал здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612875/phpstorm-algorithm-negotiation-fail).

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало. Правда пришлось убрать ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521, т.к. выдавало ошибку Unsupported KEX algorithm